# Conditional Where Clause in SQL based on selected option

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

New to SQL Server and trying to write a query that changes the where statement based on the options presented to the report user. I want to select a location and see if items for that location meet certain criteria. The criteria change based on the location. I have working queries for each option, but want to use one report to check each location.

```
SELECT
  Stuff
FROM
  Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE
  Table2.DefaultIPGateway0 LIKE N'10.'+(@Site)+'.%'
  AND Table2.IPAddress0 LIKE N'10.%' 
  Case
    When (@Site) = "1" Then AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'ABC%' AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'ABD%'
    When (@Site) = "2" Then AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'EFG%'
    When (@Site) = "3" Then AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'HIJ%' AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'STU%' AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'MNO%'
  End
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not a valid SQL statement, you can change your query like following if you want to have where condition using `CASE`.

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table2.DefaultIPGateway0 LIKE N'10.' + @Site + '.%'
    AND Table2.IPAddress0 LIKE N'10.%'
    AND (
        CASE 
            WHEN @Site = '1'
                AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'ABC%'
                AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'ABD%'
                THEN 1
            WHEN @Site = '2'
                AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'EFG%'
                THEN 1
            WHEN @Site = '3'
                AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'HIJ%'
                AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'STU%'
                AND Table1.Name0 NOT LIKE N'MNO%'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy.